# How to copy files from another computer using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy a file that is inside "C:/tempo/text.txt" from Machine B to my machine A "C:/tempo/copy.txt", I managed to copy files that are on the same computer however I need to copy from another machine... The problem is that I don't even know how to start, I thought that putting the IP address would help (saw an example) however it didn't work.
Does anyone here know how to do it? Or even sharing a guide to help me
Thank you!

this is so far what I managed to do (using the same computer)

`copy-item -path "C:\text.txt" -destination "C:\tempo\Moved_$($fileName).txt"`

and the example that didn't work

`Copy-Item -Path \\172.16.100.248\c$\tempo\test.txt -Destination C:\tempo\test.txt;`

Comment: That looks fine. Are you using an account with admin privileges on the remote machine? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @tim-ferrill I am the admin and I get this error: `Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\\172.16.100.206\c$\tempo\test.txt' because it does not exist.
At C:\copyFiles.ps1:10 char:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  -Path \\172.16.100.206\c$\tempo\test.txt -Destination C:\tempo\test.txt;
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\172.16.100.206\c$\tempo\test.txt:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand`

Comment: It's working, it just doesn't see a file with that name in that folder. Try using Get-ChildItem against the parent directory to see what files are listed. You can also use Test-Path to see if the file or folder is valid.

Comment: Still get the same error that cannot find the path.. I'm really new with ScriptShell (had to work with it today..) and I tried differents ways of doing this `Get-Childitem  \\172.16.100.206\c$\` so is it the right way?

Comment: Your PowerShell is perfect. The problem is with the path. Can you access \\172.16.100.248\c$ using Explorer?

Comment: Yes I do, but asking for password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're having a problem with credentials. Try this:

```
$User = "Domain01\User01"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "P@sSwOrd" –AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $User, $PWord

Test-Path "\\172.16.100.206\c$\tempo\test.txt" -Credential $Credential
Copy-Item -Path "\\172.16.100.206\c$\tempo\test.txt" -Destination "C:\tempo\test.txt" -Credential $Credential
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you do not like storing your password in plain text in a script you could replace the first 3 lines with `$Credential = Get-Credential` and it will prompt you for your credentials.